# Find the slope of the tangent to the curve for $y=3+4x^2-2x^3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am completing a question which asks me to find the slope of the tangent to the curve for $y=3+4x^2-2x^3$ at the point $x=a$. In Klein's book on calculus, he shows that you can find the rate of change for a term with an exponent by multiplying the variable by the exponent e.g. $x^2\to 2x$. I tried this with the equation and my answer was $y'=8a-6a$. However, the solution says that the answer should be $8a-6a^2$. Is the solution wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that if $y=x^n$ $$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=nx^{n-1}$$

If $y=3+4x^2-2x^3$, then $$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=4\times2\times x-2\times 3\times x^2$$
$$\implies \dfrac {dy}{dx}=8x-6x^2$$
Plugging in $a$, you get $8a-6a^2$.

*NOTE: $\dfrac {dy}{dx}$ is the rate of change of the function $y$ with respect to $x$.*

Comment: Thanks I stupidly forgot that $$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=nx^{n-1}$$ makes perfect sense now.

Comment: @Anobody, glad I could be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Rate of change of $2x^3=2.3x^2=6x^2.$

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if this contribution is unnecessary, but here is a common quick proof of the derivative short cut (the power rule) that you are making use of. Although I am sure the book you are using contains one as well, I emphasize understanding the proofs of these shortcut techniques because when I was a student that is what helped me grasp calculus myself.

$$y = x^{c}$$
$$ \implies ln(y) = c\cdot ln(x) $$
$$ \implies \frac{1}{y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{c}{x} $$
$$ \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{c}{x} \cdot y $$
$$ \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{c}{x} x^{c} $$
$$ \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = cx^{c-1} $$

Note that this proof uses implicit differentiation technique so it assumes you have already proven the chain rule / log rule, it can be down without assuming calculus however. Hopefully this was of some assistance.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't yet covered the chain rule/log rule. The proof in my textbook uses the binomial theorem to prove the rule. This was useful and I will return to it once I cover the chain rule.

Comment: Yes the binomial theorem is another excellent way to prove product rule without using calculus! This specific technique I posted might also come in handy in other places down the road... such as deriving strange functions such as $f(x) = x^{x}$. Cheers!